# Slow loading of google Ads

Tags: wordpress, caching, load, adsense, google-dfp

I am using DFP google ads on wordpress site. Site is loading fast, but ads are appearing much later since I switched from GAM to GPT tags. It is loading ads very slow. 
When I use `?google_console=1` it is showing me

```
443 ms to load 
6 ms to render
```

I updated lately Wordpress and Total Cache W3 plugin to latest versions, maybe there is a reason why if not in GPT tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFP is designed to load the ads asynchronously so that it doesn't slow the loading of your site down, so this is expected behavior. You are probably used to your ads loading synchronously and so it might seem they use to load faster but really they were probably slowing down the rendering of your entire site.

You can make DFP load synchronously as well though by changing the tag type in the generate tags screen of DFP (within the inventory section)

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but it is hard to give explanation like that to managers without technical knowledge. Is there any way to keep asynchronous tags but to improve speed of loading at least under 200ms.

Comment: I just had a look at the ads on our sites and they are all loading in around 400-500ms as well... But if I look at one of the test pages that I use with the DFP plugin I made they are loading in under 200ms.. see here: http://coop182.github.io/jquery.dfp.js/dfptests/

So I think the key to faster loading is to get your total page load time down (that much simpler test page loads a lot faster) so that DFP performs the fetch earlier.

Comment: My understanding of Google's async googletag DFP code was that it would load ads independent of the page's content. However, this doesn't appear to be the behavior we're seeing. When the code is active, there is a noticeable 1-2 second lag before page content (and ads) load; when disabled, the page content loads without delay.